# How to make it open in browser to click a YouTube video in the result of the Google search app?

Tags: google, youtube, search, google-search

If I remember correctly, clicking a YouTube video in the search result of the Google search app used to open YouTube in my default browser. For some reason, it now opens the Play Store link for YouTube. Can I prevent this and make it open in the browser?

[image]

Comment: @beeshyams I disabled the YouTube app a long time ago (if you see the screenshot above, you see "Enable) because I do not use the YouTube app and it cannot be uninstalled.